# What happens when a static IP address is unavailable?

Tags: ip, linux-networking

I have several Raspberry Pis configured with static IP addresses (`192.168.1.203` being one of them). I swapped out the router yesterday, and this router is using a different IP scheme (192.168.**178**.*), however the Pis still have their static IPs. What is going on in their poor little 700mhz heads? Are they still trying to get their static IPs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If they are really configured with static IP addresses, they are not **trying** to get the static IP address, they **have** it.

It may be that nothing else on the segment knows about it. But all of those devices with static IP addresses will happily continue communicating with their static IPs. You can verify this by configuring your desktop/latop/whatever to run with a static IP in that segment as well.